# Simplest way to use graphic acceleration to watch videos

Tags: hardware-acceleration

I've heard about the possibility to play videos using graphic processor of video card instead of normal processor. I've read a few tutorial but I haven't see improvement in performances, processors continue to work a lot, so maybe I just haven't enabled this feature. I'm wondering if there's a simple and quick method to do it and which are practical advantages, no technical or theoretic. I have an nvidia 8400 and I use proprietary driver (260.19.06).

Comment: What video player are you using? What makes you think it isn't using the hardware to best advantage? I'm running the same driver on an 8800, and I've yet to encounter a video that ran worse than perfectly and depending on the video encoding, with very very low CPU burden. Linking to the tutorials you have read would help us understand the your concern.

Comment: I have this bizarre issue: video card temperature increases when processors work a lot (i.e. flash on firefox), so I'm trying to reduce processor's activity and see if this benefits video card. I can perfectly reproduce videos at the moment, it's only a matter of temperatures, 85°C in 30 seconds it's not a good thing I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

There are several player supporting gpu accelerated video playback. But first you (nvidia user) should install latest nvidia drivers and vdpau libries (i guess vdpau-va-driver or vdpau-video or even just libvdpau -> synaptic will tell you).

- VLC Player >= v1.1.2 (supports a lot of formats) -> enable gpu acceleration
- Gnome Media Player (autouse best engine vlc|xine|...)
- smplayer with vdpau support

Latest nvidia packages you can find in ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
SMPlayer with vdpau support you can find in ppa:nvidia-vdpau/ppa

Use carefully, ppa's can harm your pc.

Comment: smplayer works flawlessly with my Acer Revo with Nvidia ION.  Because it's got such a poor CPU, smplayer is the only way I can play HD video on that device.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use XBMC and Boxee to play back HD and SD Movies on my Ubuntu box.
I have no problem with the same driver and a 8600. You have the option to turn on or off the VDPAU in these applications. Both apps have nice GUI. I don't now there is any official repository for XBMC for 10.10 I have compiled it from source but it was not a nightmare :)
Boxee has deb packeg to intall on Ubuntu 10.10 and it working fine.
I hope it helped :)

Comment: I didn't know about vdpau option on Boxee, I'll check, thanks, personally I use vlc. But I guess that I need to install some packages to use vdpau, I think that's part of my question.

Comment: Looks like VLC now includes experimental VDPAU support : http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=85204

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the best solution!**

You can select **Output driver** option from some *Media Players* to play best quality videos with minimum use of processors. To do so I suggest you two players: **Smplayer** and **Umplayer**.

- You can install **Smplayer** from repository.
- [Download & Install Umplayer from here](http://www.umplayer.com/).

Once installed follow these simple steps to use `graphic processor` to play videos.

- Open either player and go to `preferences` (shortcut to open preferences: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Go to <kbd>Video</kbd> tab.
- in `Output driver:` you can select your video driver to which you want to use while playing high quality videos. For example you can use **`xv`** option for *Best performance*, or you can use **`X11(slow)`** if you want to play hight definition videos in low configuration system. You can find other options like **`gl`**, **`gl(fast)`**, **`gl(fast- ATI cards)`** and so on.. Use which best suits for you configuration.
- Get help from following picture, I used `Umplayer` but it would be same for `Smplayer` also:

[image]

Please reply if you need further assistance..